# Property of an object is reset upon entering a new function

Tags: actionscript-3

```
if (mapY[i][j].buttonType != 0) //checks whether or not the button should be added
{
    mapY[i][j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, createBattleGUI); //adds event listener
    stage.addChild(mapY[i][j]); //adds it to stage
}
```

In a nested for loop (for a 2D grid), I've created a random map generator. Basically, it assigns a value to each button based on its significance (0 = don't add, 1 = start point, 2 = end point, 3 = point on the shortest path from 1 to 2). I've added an event listener that takes it to the battle stage; so whenever a button is clicked, it starts a new battle. In that function, I have this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        if (mapY[i][j].buttonType != 0)
        {
            stage.removeChild(mapY[i][j]);
        }

    }

}
```

That should remove all of the buttons. However, when I trace all of the buttonType properties, all of them are now reset to 0. If I trace it in the part that adds them to the stage, it displays correctly.

Comment: `stage.removeChild` is not removing them at all , it is only removing them from `DisplayList` , objects are still exists in memory

Comment: I should clarify this a bit. I want them removed from sight, so that I can display the battle GUI. But when it goes to the function that creates the battle GUI (which is also the function that should remove the map), somehow all of the buttonType properties on every button are reset to 0 (they start at 0).